# Unique manifold structure

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading the first chapter from the book - Foundations of Differentiable manifolds and Lie groups by Warner. There, he has given two statements to be proved as exercises.

a) Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $A$ be a subset of $M$. Fix a topology on $A$. Then there is at most one differentiable structure on $A$ such that $(A,i)$ is a submanifold of $M$, where $i$ is the inclusion map.

b) Again let $A$ be a subset of $M$. If in the relative topology, $A$ has a differentiable structure such that $(A,i)$ is a submanifold of $M$, then $A$ has a unique manifold structure (that is, unique second countable locally Euclidean topology together with a unique differentiable structure) such that $(A,i)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

I was able to prove part a). But I don't understand what to prove in part b). In the relative topology $(A,i)$ becomes a submanifold, so by part a) the differentiable structure is unique. So should I prove, no matter what topology I put on $A$, I will get the same differentiable structure? But the underlying topological spaces will be different. Is that okay? Or should I prove no matter what topology I put, such that $(A,i)$ becomes a submanifold, the two submanifolds are diffeomorphic? And how do I begin proving this? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a) says that *given a topology* on $A$, there's at most one differentiable structure on $A$ that makes $(A, i)$ a submanifold of $M$.

It's possible, once you have proved this, that for several different topologies on $A$, there are corresponding differentiable structures that make $(A, i)$ a submanifold.

Part (b) specifies a topology (the relative topology), and says that for this one topology, there is at *least* one differentiable structure compatible with it, from which you can argue that there's at most one such structure that makes $(A, i)$ a submanifold, reasoning from part "a".

But the question is "might there be some other topology for which $A$ has an differentiable structure, and for which $(i, A)$ is a submanifold?" Or to put it differently: if $(i, A)$ is a submanifold, why must the topology on $A$ be the relative topology rather than some other one?

Comment: Does (b) say that if $(i,A)$ is a submanifold then $A$ necessarily have relative topology?